# Can we send two post request using action of a single form tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send the data of a form at two different APIs. Is there any possible way out?

Comment: Don't see why not. Just add an event listener to the form's `submit` event, where you prevent the default action and make 2 separate Ajax "POST" requests, one to each API. (I've never tried this, so I'm not going to give it as an answer, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.)

Comment: The plain answer to your question title: _"Can we send two post request using action of a single form tag?
"_ is **No** — you can't put two actions on a `<form action=...>` — but of course as Robin and Garuuk say, you can always attach your own JS handler to the form-submit, and do anything you want in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Robin said, write an event handler that sends two api requests on submit.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'firstAPIUrl',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('first api was submitted');
            }
          });

           $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'secondAPIurl',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('second api submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="time" value="value">
      <input name="date" value="value">
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you use second ajax after the first one finished like :

```
<script>
  $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'firstAPIUrl',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('first api was submitted');

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'secondAPIurl',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('second api submitted');
            }
          });
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why is that better? They can be done in parallel, and I don't see any good reason to serialize the calls.

Comment: This way I work with in my scripts and put your submits into queue so you will not lose your submits and you create 1 session every time not 2 session